# Is there a way to insert an arbitrary symbol before the Python output value?

Tags: python

I'm calculating the matrix value with Python, but I want to distinguish the value of equtaion, is there a way?

x - y - 2z = 4

2x - y - z = 2

2x +y +4z = 16

I want to make the expression above like this when I print out the matrix from the function I created

1 -1 -2 | 4

2 -1 -1 | 2

2 1 4 | 16

Same as the rref result of this

1 0 0 | 24

0 1 0 | 72

0 0 1 | -26

```
def showMatrix():
    print("\n")
    for i in sd:
        for j in i:
            print(j, end="\t")
        print("\n")


def getone(pp):
    for i in range(len(sd[0])):
        if sd[pp][pp] != 1:
            q00 = sd[pp][pp]

            for j in range(len(sd[0])):
                sd[pp][j] = sd[pp][j] / q00


def getzero(r, c):
    for i in range(len(sd[0])):
        if sd[r][c] != 0:
            q04 = sd[r][c]
    
            for j in range(len(sd[0])):
                sd[r][j] = sd[r][j] - ((q04) * sd[c][j])



sd = [
    [1, 1,  2, 9],
    [2, 4, -3, 1],
    [3, 6, -5, 0]
]

showMatrix()

for i in range(len(sd)):
    getone(i)

    for j in range(len(sd)):
        if i != j:
            getzero(j, i)
    showMatrix()



print("FiNAL result")
showMatrix()
```

Comment: A divide and conquer approach is reasonable. First write a function to take 4 numbers and convert it into an equation. After that, it would be easy enough to convert a 3x4 matrix into 3 equations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which takes a list of 4 numbers and returns a string representing an equation in `x,y,z`. It handles coefficients which are negative, zero, or +/-1 appropriately:

```
def make_equation(nums):
    coefficients = nums[:3]
    variables = 'xyz'
    terms = []
    for c,v in zip(coefficients,variables):
        if c == 0:
            continue
        elif c == 1:
            coef = ''
        elif c == -1:
            coef = '-'
        else:
            coef = str(c)
        terms.append(coef + v)
    s = ' + '.join(terms)
    s = s.replace('+ -','- ')
    return s + ' = ' + str(nums[3])
```

Typical example:

```
make_equation([2,-3,1,6])
```

With output:

```
'2x - 3y + z = 6'
```